# following a course on spring boot data jpa - can't resolve issue with creating a table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Started following a course on data jpa in spring boot using PostgreSQL.
Tutor's log when starting the app shows this:
[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pypB.png)

meanwhile i get no such feedback but have all the same code.
these are my app properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tutorialdb
spring.datasource.username=********
spring.datasource.password=********
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa-show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

this is my pom.xml with all the necessary dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and lastly my student class which is supposed to create my entities for the database:

```
package com.example.demo.student;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String email;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Long id,
                   String firstName,
                   String email,
                   String lastName,
                   Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.email = email;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String firstName,
                   String email,
                   String lastName,
                   Integer age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.email = email;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{"+
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + lastName +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

this is my log:

```
2021-11-19 15:13:02.643  INFO 11480 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.11 on DESKTOP-74ECT9M with PID 11480 (C:\Users\Novak\Desktop\Work\Spring initializr\demo\target\classes started by Novak in C:\Users\Novak\Desktop\Work\Spring initializr\demo)
2021-11-19 15:13:02.647  INFO 11480 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-19 15:13:03.497  INFO 11480 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-19 15:13:03.511  INFO 11480 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-19 15:13:04.283  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-11-19 15:13:04.294  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-11-19 15:13:04.294  INFO 11480 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
2021-11-19 15:13:04.371  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-11-19 15:13:04.371  INFO 11480 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1641 ms
2021-11-19 15:13:04.587  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-19 15:13:04.637  INFO 11480 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-11-19 15:13:04.755  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-19 15:13:04.841  INFO 11480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-19 15:13:05.009  INFO 11480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-19 15:13:05.024  INFO 11480 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2021-11-19 15:13:05.623  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-19 15:13:05.633  INFO 11480 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-19 15:13:05.676  WARN 11480 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-11-19 15:13:06.035  INFO 11480 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-11-19 15:13:06.046  INFO 11480 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.964 seconds (JVM running for 4.488)
```

Comment: Am I correct, that you expect to see a 'create table....' in the logging?

Comment: yes, as shown in the log picture i provided of the tutorial at the start of my question

Comment: Having `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` will only create the table if the table does not exist. Have you checked your DB? Or use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` to test (this will recreate the tabel each time you start the application)

Comment: ok so I realized that in the database the table is actually being created it's just that my log  doesn't really give me any information on it, why is this?

Comment: Should be `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` versus `spring.jpa-show-sql` in your props